# My python loop through a dataframe slows down over time

Tags: python, performance, loops, dataframe, nested

I'm looping through a very large dataframe(11361 x 22679) and converting the values of each row to a pixel image using pyplot. So in the end I should have 11361 images with 151 x 151 pixels (I add 0's to the end to make it square).
allDF is a list of 33 DataFrames that correspond to the 33 subirectories in newFileNames the images need to save to.

I've tried deleting each DataFrame and image at the end of each iteration. 
I've tried converting the float values to int.
I've tried gc.collect() at the end of each iteration (even though I know it's redundant)
I've taken measures not to store any additional values by always referencing the original data.

The only thing that helps is if I process one frame at a time. It still slows down, but because there are less iterations it's not as slow.  So, I think the inner loop or one of the functions is the issue.

```
def shape_pixels(imglist):
    for i in range(122):
        imglist.append(0.0)
    imgarr = np.array(imglist).reshape((151,151))
    imgarr.reshape((151,151))
    return imgarr

def create_rbg_image(subpath,imgarr,imgname):
    # create/save image
    img = plt.imshow(imgarr, cmap=rgbmap)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.savefig(dirpath+subpath+imgname,
                transparent=True,
                bbox_inches=0,pad_inches=0)

for i in range(len(allDF)):
    for j in range(len(allDF[i])):
        fname = allDF[i]['File Name'].iloc[j][0:36]
        newlist = allDF[i].iloc[j][1:].tolist()
        newarr = shape_pixels(allDF[i].iloc[j][1:].tolist())
        create_rbg_image(newFileNames[i]+'\\',shape_pixels(allDF[i].iloc[j][1:].tolist()),allDF[i]['File Name'].iloc[j][0:36])
```

I'd like to be able to run the code for the entire dataset and just come back to it when it's done, but I ran it overnight and got less than 1/3 of the way through. If it continues to slow down I'll never be done.
The first minute generates over 150 images The second generates 80. Then 48, 32, 27, and so on.. eventually it takes several minutes to create just one.

I don

Comment: What is the memory usage like?

Comment: just spitballin', but try to add a `plt.close('all')` at the bottom of your create_rgb_image

Comment: {'total': 8450404352,
 'available': 3092492288,
 'percent': 63.4,
 'used': 5357912064,
 'free': 3092492288}

Comment: plt.close('all') helped SIGNIFICANTLY, but it's still slowing down quite a bit. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

plot.close('all')  helped significantly, but I switched to using PIL and hexadec values, This was significantly more efficient and I was able to generate all 11k+ images in under 20 minutes